# Magento get all products details in json format

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, json

I am using magento 1.9.3 version.  I got the specific products details in json format. Now i want show all the products details in json format.   I referred some more sites, There is not examples of these problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code snippet we can use for get all products into in json format.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('cetalog/product')->getCollection(); // This will return all products.
$product = $product->getData() // This will convert product collection into the array. 
return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($product)); // Return Json response from Controller
```